# How display image in GL View landscape or portrait according to its taken position

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, users take picture either landscape or portrait. After taking picture, transfer it to another **UIViewController** with following code :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let sp = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("sendPhoto") as! sendPhotoScreen
sp.photoImage = newImage     
self.presentViewController(sp, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In sendPhotoScreen, how can I display image as portrait

[image: portrait]

if it is taken as portrait, and how can I display image as landscape

[image: landscape]

if it is taken as landscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check with the aspect ratio.

```
if image.size.height > image.size.width {
    potraitImageView.image = image
}
else {
    landscapeImageView.image = image
}
```